# Android RPG game for busy people

Tags: android, game

I love RPG's but only have 5 to 10 minutes at a time to play, here and there through the day.

Can anyone recommend an Android based game that has the following?

- Can drop it at any time, without penalty
- can easily pick it up, and carry on where left off
- has in-game way of tracking what you were doing, or going to do
- does not force perma-death* as the only gameplay
- features some form of magic
- features some form of stealth
- has some form of character progression, eg skill or levels

Optional bonus features

- magic and stealth on same character
- online multiplayer ;)

*(by perma-death, I mean when your character dies, you're forced to start over from the beginning)

Comment: emulators - those can pick up and resume right where you left off very quickly, and there are tons of games (but I find the non-real time ones work better on android, such as fire emblem)

Answer (score 2):

## [Doom & Destiny](http://doomanddestiny.com/)

Doom & Destiny is a cross-platform turn-based RPG. It has both [paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hb.doom_and_destiny) and [free (ad supported)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hb.doom_and_destiny_free) versions on Android.

**Synopsis:**

> Four nerds, drawn into a fantasy world and mistaken for heroes, have to battle their way through a massive, crazy adventure and defeat a preposterous villian!
> This great RPG has magic, dungeons, pizza, and jokes galore

**Features:**

- Turn-based: "time" does not progress unless you make a move. This means you **can drop it at any time**, and it'll still be at the same place when you're back
- Stores your saved progress on the cloud so you could access it anytime and **pick up where you left off** even on different devices
- The characters have a journal that **keeps track of your previous and current quests**
- **No perma death**: If one or more characters are defeated, you could spend some resources and revive them
- **Contains magic spells**: It features a spellcaster character that learns several magic spells as the game progresses
- It either **doesn't have stealth**, or I haven't gotten that far yet. The ninja character is all dagger and no cloak
- **Has 100 skill levels** and plenty of ability and weapon upgrades
- No multiplayer yet, but it's being advertised for the sequel

Answer (score 0):

There's a fun one called NetHack.

It's not what it sounds like, it's a dungeon-crawler type game with a lot of game mechanics and potions and spells, and pretty much anything you can ask for out of a fantasy game. It doesn't have much in the way of graphics (the "classic mode" actually uses letters and symbols instead of sprites) but it is pretty decent.
Nothing moves unless you're doing something, so you have all the time to plan, not to say that makes it easy.
Just know that you don't want to just go around firing wands, because while there a blue potion will do the same thing every time you use it in that game, it's something new next time you restart. The only consistent item description is that *Scrolls of Identification* are always the cheapest.

It is mainly advertised as a Windows game but it's got clones on every platform I can think of (Android, Linux, Mac, in-browser, Nokia, whatever GP32 is, even DS!).

There are a ton of sites dedicated to it, so it's kinda hard to find the useful stuff right away, so I'll compile a quick list:

- Google Play store link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbd.NetHack
- Fan-made intro: http://thegreatestgameyouwilleverplay.com/
- Official (and kind lame) page: http://nethack.org/
- Wiki with EVERYTHING to know: http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Nethack is all about permadeath, which the question rules out. Oh, and your description of Nethack is wrong on several counts: it's from the Unix world (not Windows); you do want to fire wands (but carefully); scrolls of identification don't have a consistent identification, only an unambiguous price (if you know how to calculate it) but that's the case for many items (and all items' base prices are consistent).